# Lemma 6.7, Lang, Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying lemma 6.7 in Lang's *Algebra*, which says "Let $G$ be a finite group and let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing the order of $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of index $p$. Then $H$ is normal."

The proof starts by saying, "Let $N(H)=N$ be the normalizer of $H$. Then $N=G$ or $N=H$."

Supposing this is true, I understand the rest of the proof, but I have troubles seeing why necessarily we need to have $N=G$ or $N = H$. Could someone explain this detail to me? Thanks!

Comment: The normalizer will be a subgroup of order divisible by $|H|$ and dividing the order of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always true that $\;H\le N(=N_G(H))\le G\;$ , so

$$p=[G:H]=[G:N]\cdot[N:H]\ldots\ldots\text{but $\,p\,$ is a prime...}$$